# Posicionamiento fluido con imágenes de altura variable

Tags: css, grid

Muy buenas,

Tengo un contenedor y una serie de imágenes variable en numero, aparecen o no según condiciones. La cosa es que una de ellas es muchísimo mas alta que el resto y no se como hacer para que las de abajo puedan recolocarse de manera fluida (tal como indican las flechas grises del esquema siguiente). Entiendo que esto ocurre porque se muestran en inline-block y se comportan como si fueran texto pero no se como solucionarlo. Utilizar flexbox no es una opción para mi por temas de compatibilidad con IE. He probado usar "float: left" y el resultado es el mismo.

Muchas gracias!

```css
#contenedor{
  width: 500px;
}

.box{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.peq{
  height: 160px;
}

.gra{
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box gra"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
  <div class="box peq"></div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes poner un poco de código de lo que has puesto en el css? Yo he hecho una página de prueba con un ```float:left``` y si que me funciona, tanto en IE y chrome.

Comment: Pues resulta complicado, en realidad estoy utilizando una herramienta que genera el código base y yo implemento por encima, así que es difícil porque programo de manera indirecta. Trataré de revisarlo si dices que si que te ha funcionado. Yo he tratado de hacer un ejemplo muy básico con codepen y sigue sin salirme. https://codepen.io/AdriaFa/pen/RzOREV

Answer (score 3):

Para ver estos grids tienes que pensar fuera de la caja "think out the box"

Estamos acostumbrados a ver las estructuras de esta manera:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
--------------
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
--------------
9 | 10
```

Cuando este tipo de grids usa este otro tipo (columnas):

```
1 | 4 | 7 | 9
2 | 5 | 8 | 10
3 | 6 |   |
```

Esto no significa que tu segundo item lo tengas que meter en la primera columna. Puedes pintar los items en el orden normal y después cambiarlos de orden con CSS o JS.

Tienes muchos ejemplos en codepen y es es facil buscar estos ejemplos por ***Pinterest grid*** o ***Masonry***  esta ultima  es una librería javascript para conseguir este tipo de layouts.

La cuestion es, **¿hacer este tipo de grids requiere JS?**.
No necesariamente.

Ejemplos:

- [Separar contenedores en columnas](https://codepen.io/vxdiazdel/pen/zKQQZe)
- [Usando column](https://codepen.io/rippedspine/pen/EbJpg)
- [Column](https://codepen.io/roger-mc/pen/zpVexg)
- [Usando isotope (libreria js)](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/ybaoro)

**Snippet con tu ejemplo no es responsive:**

```css
#contenedor{
  width: 500px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.box{
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.peq{
  height: 160px;
}

.gra{
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box peq"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box peq"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box peq"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="box peq"></div>
    <div class="box gra"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```